# Function to simplify code in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".b0").hover(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('data');
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#imagen").attr('src', src);
        $("#vinculo").attr('href', href);
    });
    $(".b1").hover(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('data');
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#imagen").attr('src', src);
        $("#vinculo").attr('href', href);
    });
})
```

But I can't simplify it with a function. I tried several times and ways...

Comment: Given that both event handlers do the exact same thing, just use `$('.b0, .b1').hover(...` Or better yet - put the same class on both elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".b0 , .b1").hover(function () {
            $("#imagen").attr('src', $(this).attr('data'));
            $("#vinculo").attr('href', $(this).attr('href'));
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define the event handler in an external function, then access the element with `event.currentTarget` instead of `this`, with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function hoverHandler(event) {
        var src = $(event.currentTarget).attr('data');
        var href = $(event.currentTarget).attr('href');
        $("#imagen").attr('src', src);
        $("#vinculo").attr('href', href);
    }

    $(".b0").hover(hoverHandler);
    $(".b1").hover(hoverHandler);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a function, you need to pass `this` to it explicitly.

```
function hoverHandler(element) {
    var src = $(element).attr('data');
    var href = $(element).attr('href');
    $("#imagen").attr('src', src);
    $("#vinculo").attr('href', href);
}      
$(".b0").hover(function() {
    hoverHandler(this));
});
$(".b1").hover(function() {
    hoverHandler(this));
});
```

But the simplest solution is to just combine the selectors:

```
$(".b0, .b1").hover(function () {
    var src = $(this).attr('data');
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#imagen").attr('src', src);
    $("#vinculo").attr('href', href);
});
```